Building docker image always fails on azure devops as the pipeline cannot find the csproj files
my folder structure of the ASP.NET web app looks like this:
MyApp.Backend/
├── src/
│   ├── MyApp/
│   │   ├── MyApp.csproj
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── Core/
│   │   ├── MyLibrary1/
│   │   │   └── MyLibrary1.csproj
│   └── External/
│       ├── MyLibrary2/
│       │   └── MyLibrary2.csproj

So dockerfile is in the MyApp.Backend/src/MyApp/dockerfile.
Dockerfile itself looks like this (generated from both Rider and VS2022):
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
# Copy project files
COPY ["src/MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "src/MyApp/"]
COPY ["src/Core/MyLibrary1/MyLibrary1.csproj", "src/Core/MyLibrary1/"]
COPY ["src/External/MyLibrary2/MyLibrary2.csproj", "src/External/MyLibrary2/"]

# Restore NuGet packages
RUN dotnet restore "src/MyApp/MyApp.csproj"

# Copy everything else
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/MyApp"

# etc.....

No matter what I do, or how do I run it,
dockerfile can never find the project files:
#9 [build  4/13] COPY [MyApp/MyApp.csproj, MyApp/]
#9 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 828adade-9126-45c5-a536-dc1f57fd1350::4yps4ixymnuqpupflyaiyicxz: "/MyApp/MyApp.csproj": not found

#10 [build  9/13] COPY [External/MyLibrary2/MyLibrary2.csproj, External/MyLibrary2/MyLibrary2.csproj/]
#10 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 828adade-9126-45c5-a536-dc1f57fd1350::4yps4ixymnuqpupflyaiyicxz: "/External/MyLibrary2/MyLibrary2.csproj": not found

#11 [build  8/13] COPY [Core/MyLibrary1/MyLibrary1.csproj, Core/MyLibrary1/]
#11 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 828adade-9126-45c5-a536-dc1f57fd1350::4yps4ixymnuqpupflyaiyicxz: "/Core/MyLibrary1/MyLibrary1.csproj": not found

I've tried playing around the WORKDIR command but to no avail. This is relatively standard folder structure of a microservice but docker just seems it cannot find the related csproj files.

@KevinLu-MSFT unfortunately still no success. I would prefer not to move my dockerfile, so I've tried setting the   .... in my csproj file but still it cannot files

You can try to use the method2 in the answer to use the script task to run the docker. In this case, you don't need to move the dockerfile and don't need to change the content in the csproj file.

If you are using the Docker task in Azure DevOps Pipeline, the working directory will be set to the same path as the dockerfile by default. There is no built-in argument in task can change the behavior.
In this case, it will not be able to find the .csproj files in different folders.
To solve this issue, you can use the following two methods:
Method1: You can put the Dockerfile to the same path as src folder.
For example:
MyApp.Backend/
├── Dockerfile
├── src/
│   ├── MyApp/
│   │   ├── MyApp.csproj
│   │   
│   ├── Core/
│   │   ├── MyLibrary1/
│   │   │   └── MyLibrary1.csproj
│   └── External/
│       ├── MyLibrary2/
│       │   └── MyLibrary2.csproj

Dockerfile task:
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: build
  inputs:
    repository: test
    command: build
    Dockerfile: MyApp.Backend/src/MyApp/Dockerfile

Then the csproj files can be found during the docker build process.
Method2: You can use the PowerShell/Bash/Command Line task to run the docker command and set the working directory to the same path as src.
For example:
steps:
- script: 'docker build -f  src/MyApp/Dockerfile  -t test .'
  workingDirectory: MyApp.Backend

In this case, it can find the .csproj files in the subfolder of src.
